# Cannot disable mysql login without password on AlpineLinux of Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, passwords, alpine-linux

I am really stuck and I need your help.

My project is to build wordpress-installed website with 3 containers: Nginx, Wordpress + php-fpm and mysql on Docker. All containers are built on alpine:latest image.

I successfully launched website and everything works except for one thing: to disable mysql login without password.

My mysql's container is working on these condition:

- Base Image: alpine:latest
- Package: mysql, mysql-client
- Version: mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.9-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

I believe I have tried enough solutions such as:

- Set password on root user `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('xxxxxx');`
- Remove anonymous users
- Check if there are description of user and password on /etc/my.cnf
- Change root host from 'localhost' to '%'

Yet, I could login without password on root user.

This is the screenshot after I did those 3 things.

As you can see, root user has passoword but I can login without entering any password on root user.

[image]

What I want to achive is like this:

```
# mysql - u root
Enter Password: // Just enter 'Enter'
ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: No)
```

I do appreciate your help.

**Update: 2021-06-02**

I tried to create a similar condition using debian:buster because official mysql docker uses debian:buster-slim. Here is [official mysql image](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/b11f06b0d202e7b0f97b000e158fc4fc869d2194/5.7/Dockerfile.debian).

- Base Image: debian:buster
- Package: default-mysql-server

I easily achieved to disable mysql login without password by setting password on root user.

So I wonder if it is because of alpine...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it , I am not sure if this will work for accessing the server from application side, but you can access mysql prompt by storing this user and password at OS level.

1. use a client section of the ~/.my.cnf file, and add the credentials there.

> ```
> [client]
> user=root
> password=somepassword
> ```

2. You can add a new section [client] to you /etc/my.cnf and you can add the credential under [client] tag.

> ```
> [client]
> user=root
> password=somepassword
> ```

3. Password-less authentication using [mysql_config_editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html)

> ```
> shell> mysql_config_editor set --login-path=dbadmin_local --host=localhost --user=dbadmin --password
> Enter password:
> ```

You can add multiple hostnames and passwords by changing the login path. If the password is changed, you can run this utility again, which updates the password in the file:

> ```
> shell> mysql_config_editor set --login-path=dbadmin_remote -- host=35.186.157.16 --user=dbadmin --password
> Enter password:
> ```

If you want to log in to 35.186.157.16 using the dbadmin user, you can simply execute mysql --login-path=dbadmin_remote:

> shell> mysql --login-path=dbadmin_remote

To connect to localhost, you can simply execute mysql

> shell> mysql